# In how many ways can $3$ couples sit around a round table such that men and women alternate and none of the couples sit together?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

In how many ways  can $3$ couples sit around a round table such that men and women alternate and none of the couples sit together?

My solution goes like this:

> We denote the $3$ couples by the symbols $(B_1,G_1),(B_2,G_2)$ and $(B_3,G_3)$ where each such ordered pair i.e $(B_i,G_i)$ ( where $B_i's$ and $G_i's$ are men and  ladies respectively) constitute a couple. Now, we consider the positions of $B_1$ that are possible in the given arrangement. We observe that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the only candidates that can sit on either side of $B_1.$ We have two cases:
>
> **Case 1:** This is the case when the arrangement of $B_1,G_2,G_3$ are as shown below in the figure:
>
> $$G_2,B_1,G_3$$
>
> Now, neither $B_2,B_1$ can sit on the other side of $G_2$ as $B_1$ is already  seated and $B_2$ cant sit beside $G_2$ as otherwise the given condition in the question would be violated. So,  only  $B_3$ can be seated on the other side of $G_2.$ The arrangement would then proceed to look like this:
>
> $$B_3,G_2,B_1,G_3$$
>
> We continue our reasoning. Now, similarly, only $B_2$ can be seated on the other side of $G_3.$ The arrangement would now look like:
>
> $$B_3,G_2,B_1,G_3,B_2$$
>
> We must not forget,  that the couples are seated on a round table and hence there is only one possible position for placing $G_1$, i.e between $B_3$ and $B_2.$ Placing $G_1$ there, we find, indeed it is a valid arrangement. Our final arrangement looks like this:
>
> $$B_3,G_2,B_1,G_3,B_2,G_1$$
>
> We now proceed to develop Case 2.
>
> **Case 2:** In this case,  we assume   $B_1,G_2,G_3$ are arranged like this, as shown below in the figure:
>
> $$G_3,B_1,G_2$$
>
> Reasoning similarly, in the previous analogous case, we  find, $B_2$ and $B_3$ must be seated in the vacant positions  beside $G_3$ and  $G_2$ respectively. The arrangement would begin to look like this:
>
> $$B_2,G_3,B_1,G_2,B_3$$
>
> Again, we note that if $G_1$ is placed in between $B_2$ and  $B_3$ then it becomes a valid arrangement. So, the final arrangement looks like this:
>
> $$B_2,G_3,B_1,G_2,B_3,G_1$$
>
> But then again, as the arrangements are done on a round table, we note that both the final  arrangements of Case 1 and Case 2 i.e $$B_3,G_2,B_1,G_3,B_2,G_1$$ and $$B_2,G_3,B_1,G_2,B_3,G_1$$
> are the same or rather  equivalent.  So, wherever we place $B_1$ to start the process, it doesn't matter as we will get only one possible arrangement only.  So, the number of possible arrangement is $1.$

Now, I am totally confused whether my solution is correct or not? This is because the answer given is $2$ instead of $1$ possible arrangement(s). I seem not to get a hold of this dilemma.

**EDIT:** As it seems from the comments, in this problem, reflected arrangements are considered to be different in a round table  arrangement. While, in my solution, I assumed them to be  equivalent. This was the cause of disparity between the answers. But, now I want to know how to understand *whether two arrangements are reflections of each other or not. As because, in this problem I had no idea that the two possible arrangements I considered in the two cases are  mere reflections of each other. To be precise: I  am confused and I want to know how to find all possible  reflected arrangement for a given arrangement. I seem to have no idea  about these terminologies /results, or better to say:  **the notion of  "reflections of a particular arrangement" was  completely  unknown/new to me up until this day**.*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145648/discussion-on-question-by-fdst-zfsy-in-how-many-ways-can-3-couples-sit-around); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve these type of questions without writing the cases as you did, i suggest you using **[principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)**

Our logic is that ( the number of all alternating arrangements) - (the number of alternating arrangements that contain at least one adjacent couple).

Now, i assume that you know how to apply P.I.E,so

$$2!\times 3! - \bigg(\binom{3}{1}\times2\times 4-\binom{3}{2}\times 2\times3+ \binom{3}{3}\times 2\times 2 \bigg)=12-24+18-4=2$$

- $2!\times 3! \rightarrow$ Place firstly men by $(3-1)!=2!$ ,and after that, place the women the gaps between men by $3!$ ways.
- $\binom{3}{1}\times2\times 4 \rightarrow$ Firslty select one couple to make them together. After that , place $2$ men and $2$ women around circle by $(2-1)!\times 2!=2$ ways.Now, we obtained $4$ gaps to place this couple and their inter arrangements can be done only one way, because when this couple place an suitable place, they should obey alternating sitting rule.
- $\binom{3}{2}\times2 \times3 \rightarrow$ Select two couple by $C(3,2)$ to place them together. When we place a man and a woman, we have $2$ gaps to place first couple.After that ,now we have $3$ gaps to place the other couple.Again, the inter arrangements of couples does not important ,because there will be only one sitting rule to obey alternating sitting rule.
- $\binom{3}{3}\times 2\times 2 \rightarrow$ All couples are together $C(3,3)$. Then, if we think each couple as a single object, these $3$ couples can be placed $(3-1)!=2!$ ways.However, if we place the first couple as $(W,M)$ according to clockwise, then the second couple will also be placed as $(W,M)$ and so on, but if we place the first couple as $(M,W)$ according to clockwise, then the second couple will also be placed as $(M,W)$ and so on.Hence, the inter position of couples in first arrangement is important and there are $2$ distinct inter sitting for couples.